# How to check a hashed password against database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, password-hash, php-password-hash

I am looking to check the username and password that are entered are equal to the username and password stored in mysql database.

I have used `password_hash()` to hash the password and stored them into table. But I don't know, how to check if they are the same or not.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $usernameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$servername = "localhost";
$serverUsername = "root";
$serverPassword = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $serverUsername, $serverPassword);
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'users');

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_logons WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($query , 'ss' , $username , $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);
    $password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    mysqli_stmt_close($query);

}

$usernameErr = $passwordErr = "";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Also, do I have to escape the password input if it is hashed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `input` password hashed again and ***before*** binding it with your prepare statement. You need to make sure, you are using same encryption method, which was used for storing.

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);
$password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 

mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($query , 'ss' , $username , $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
```

---

**Edited:**

As suggested by @Devon in comment, you could also use **[`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)**

Comment: You really should use password_verify

Comment: How would I go about using the password_verify?

Comment: @Justanotherprogrammer assuming `username` is unique, then select password for the specific username and then compare.